# Konva Clipping, Layering and Dragging

Tags: jquery, konvajs

I trying to mask konva layers and objects with a png file and keep them independently draggable (and, if possible, attach drag & drop events thereafter). There are answers elsewhere for building masked images but not for layer elements within the stack.

So I'm looking at a set of layers something like this:
[proposed stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwWnY.png)

With a final appearance of something like this: [final appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kT0H0.png)

Obviously examples would be great, but as much as anything I need to know if it's even possible.

Comment: Definitely possible - have a look at this just as an example of what is possible. I think you may not need the ping overlay with the cutout. I don't have the draggable text in this example but you should be able to add a text or image-of-text shape on to the inner layer easily enough. See https://codepen.io/JEE42/pen/VzPNQK

Comment: Superb. Only just started looking at Konva and my first project needs to be quite involved so Big tx :)

Comment: Would you mind if I put the gist of the project into an answer? I want to lay down a good body of usable snippets for folk who walk this path later and links to external sites are always at risk in some way.

Comment: Will do ... however pressure of work right now means I can't but very shortly the project will have some of it's loose threads tied up. Although I haven't implemented everything from your code yet it's been super helpful.